How to find the Galois group of an infinite Galois extension? For example $\mathbb{Q}(\mathbb{\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}})$.
I know that this is a very broad question, but I am especially interest in the case of the Galois extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}}) = \mathbb{Q}( \{ \sqrt{-1} \} \cup \sqrt{p} \mid p \text{ prime number })$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
I know that it really is a Galois extension since I have already shown that it is normal and separable ($\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{Q}) = 0$).
In view of the finite case (if we only add finitely many square roots of prime numbers) one can compute (assuming that the square roots of primes are linear independent if we view $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\mathbb{Q}})$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$) that the Galois group must be $C_{2}^{n} = C_2 \times \dots \times C_2$.
So my conjecture would be that the Galois group must $C_2^{\mathbb{N}}$. There must be some limit argument which I am missing.
I am thankful for any insights.

The Galois group of an infinite extension is obtained as an inverse limit of the finite Galois subextensions. You can find a handout from George Bergman here, in PostScript.

For infinite extensions, the Galois theory is substantially different from that known for finite extensions and new notions such as projective limits and Krull topology are used for this purpose. In this ad hoc context we have that the Galois group $G(K|K_n)$ is compact and totally discontinuous. (see details in L’Arithmétique des corps by Paulo Ribenboim).
